# friend cannot access private variables?

Tags: c++, friend

```
class LongInt
{

    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, const LongInt & integer);

...
}

ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, LontInt & container)
{
    os << container.number.size(); //error here


    return os;
}
```

error: 'std::vector LongInt::number' is private
         vector number;
                     ^

I don't understand why I can't access the variable, does it have to do something with the fact that the member variable is a vector?

Comment: -1 **not the real code** (given code has syntax errors and mis-spelings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not a friend of that function: the signature is different. Note `const` modifier of the second parameter.

Comment: ah, weird, it should have given me a different error msg.

Comment: @OnTheFly No, it shouldn't. This because `friend` specifier does not obligate you to have function with specified signature. If you are trying to use private members in outer class/global function it will check whether this class/global function is in the friend list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `const` in the declaration before `LongInt`, which makes the signatures different, and the compiler doesn't think it's the same function that you declared as friend.